# trying to make next button in javascript to display json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to display the json array according to certain start and end indices. I did displayed it all but when I click on first button it doesn't work. Here is my code .. after clicking on first button it says "this.data is undefined"
any help ??

```js
   

   function GridLibrary(data) {
this.data = data;

 }
  GridLibrary.prototype.display = function() {
 var html = [];
 html.push("<table >\n<tbody>");
 html.push("<tr>");
 for ( var propertyNames in this.data[0]) {
  html.push("<th>" + propertyNames + "</th>");
 }
 html.push("</tr>");
 // loop through the array of objects
 for (var i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++) {
  item = this.data[i];
  html.push("<tr>");
  for ( var key in item) {
   html.push("<td>" + item[key] + "</td>");
  }
  html.push("</tr>");

 }
 html.push("<table>\n</tbody>");
   $('body').append(html.join(""));
};
var grid = new GridLibrary();
$("#first").click(function() {
 //size = parseInt(document.getElementById("listsize").value, 10);
 startIndex = 3;
 endIndex = 6;
 grid.display();
 
});
```

the Grid.jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var json = [ {
        "id" : 1,
        "name" : "name1",
        "age" : 10,
        "feedback" : "feedback1"
    }, {
        "id" : 2,
        "name" : "name2",
        "age" : 90,
        "feedback" : "feedback2"
    }, {
        "id" : 3,
        "name" : "name3",
        "age" : 30,
        "feedback" : "feedback3"
    }, {
        "id" : 4,
        "name" : "name4",
        "age" : 50,
        "feedback" : "feedback4"
    }, {
        "id" : 5,
        "name" : "name5",
        "age" : 55,
        "feedback" : "feedback5"
    }, {
        "id" : 6,
        "name" : "name6",
        "age" : 68,
        "feedback" : "feedback6"
    }, {
        "id" : 7,
        "name" : "name7",
        "age" : 57,
        "feedback" : "feedback7"
    }, {
        "id" : 8,
        "name" : "name8",
        "age" : 89,
        "feedback" : "feedback8"
    }, {
        "id" : 9,
        "name" : "name9",
        "age" : 65,
        "feedback" : "feedback9"
    }, {
        "id" : 10,
        "name" : "name10",
        "age" : 54,
        "feedback" : "feedback10"
    }, {
        "id" : 11,
        "name" : "name11",
        "age" : 51,
        "feedback" : "feedback11"
    }, {
        "id" : 12,
        "name" : "name12",
        "age" : 97,
        "feedback" : "feedback12"
    } ];
    new GridLibrary(json).display();
</script>
```

Comment: 1) Have you defined the constructor properly? 2) I would pass `startIndex` and `endIndex` into the function call as parameters: `grid.display(3, 6);`

Comment: could you please link up `GridLibrary` cdn here, so that we could have a try on fiddle?

Comment: *"it doesn't work"* isn't a proper problem description that provides meaningful information that anyone can troubleshoot

Comment: @charlietfl i updated it please have a look

Comment: @ameenulla0007 i updated it please have a look

Comment: So where is the `GridLibrary` constructor that shows data being bound to the object?

Comment: a quick question, why do you require Object here, while you can do this easily, by keeping parameters.!

Answer (score 1):

I've made a few assumptions here.

1) Your constructor should accept a parameter which will be your data:

```
function GridLibrary(data){
  this.data = data;
  return this;
}
```

2) This will be used like so:

```
var grid = new GridLibrary(json);
```

3) You should then pass in `startIndex` and `endIndex` as parameters to `display()`:

```
grid.display(0, 11);
```

or

```
grid.display(3, 6);
```

and change the method to accept those arguments:

```
GridLibrary.prototype.display = function(startIndex, endIndex) {...
```

4) Finally you should change the HTML (not append) to a specific `div` otherwise you will overwrite your `first` button:

```
$('#body').html(html.join(""));
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/trhz34nd/12/)

Comment: well, A perfect solution perhaps.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just by looking at your code, it seems like you don't close your table tag properly. The last html.push adds a new `<table>`, instead of `</table>`. They are also in the wrong order, it should be `</tbody></table>`

edit: fixed formatting

Comment: the console says this.data is undefined